# Xcode project to Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, xcode, project

I do most of my home development in Xcode, however my classes require me to use Visual Studio 2010. I am curious if there is some tool that can convert my Xcode project to Visual Studio projects and back and structure the files the way the ides want them to be?

The programs I am writing are OS independent.

Answer (score 3):

You might want to consider using a meta-make such as [CMake](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CMake) that can generate both Visual Studio and Xcode project files.

It's probably not as ideal for you since you'll need to write the CMake file and then fix up both the Xcode and Visual Studio projects to your liking (though I believe CMake has some support for project organisation in Visual Studio—not sure about Xcode) rather than doing a straight conversion, but it would allow you to work in Xcode and submit as a Visual Studio project.

Comment: You might also be interested in using [premake](http://industriousone.com/premake).